Mostrar listado de registros faltantes
Hola a todos espero me puedan ayudar a realizar lo siguiente..
Tengo un php que lo que hace es sacar los registros de una tabla y mostrarlos en un listado por fechas.
esos datos que arroja la consulta son registros almacenados de un listado de vehículos, pero hay algunos que por condiciones de reparaciones u otras no salen y esa información de esos vehículos como no esta en la base de datos no se muestra en el listado (obviamente) como hago para que en una tabla por aparte me Muestre esos vehículos que no tienen datos, es decir si hay 20 vehículos y se muestra la información de 12 como hago para mostrar la información de los faltantes (como le doy el listado general de los 20 vehículos al sistema para que los que Esten los omita y solo muestre los que no)
este es el script del listado de los que estan... perdonen el código y la versión pero es para llevar una idea de como proceder...
mil gracias..
<table width="100%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table grilla2 table" data-sort="table">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th width="74" height="30" bgcolor="#FF6600"><span id="tabla"><font face="verdana"><b>FECHA</b></font></span></th>
  <th width="123" bgcolor="#FF6600"><span id="tabla"><font face="verdana"><b>CONDUCTOR</b></font></span></th>  
  <th width="81" bgcolor="#FF6600"><span id="tabla"><font face="verdana"><b>VEHICULO</b></font></span></th>
  <th width="88" bgcolor="#FF6600"><span id="tabla">TIEMPO / DURACION</span></th>
    <th width="166" bgcolor="#FF6600">OPERARIOS  DE SANEAMIENTO</th>  
  <th width="113" bgcolor="#FF6600"><span id="tabla"><font face="verdana"><b>MUNICIPIO</b></font></span></th>
  <th width="149" bgcolor="#FF6600">CORREG / RUTA ADICIONAL</th>
  <th width="156" bgcolor="#FF6600">NOVEDAD VIAJE</th>
  <th width="166" bgcolor="#FF6600">FALLOS MECANICOS</th> 
</tr>
<?php  
 // CONEXION-------------------------

$query = "SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE codigo_viaje > '' AND nomostrar !='off' AND fecha_reporte BETWEEN '".$fecha1w."' AND '".$fecha2w."' AND municipio='".$municipiow."' ORDER BY fecha_reporte ASC, hora1 ASC, hora1correg ASC";

  $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
echo "<tbody>";
if(($row["dia"]!="DOMINGO")&&($row["festivo"]=="SI")){
$diafest1="FESTIVO";
}else{
$diafest1="";
}
if($row["permiso"]=="si"){
$permiso2="(DE PERMISO)";
}else{
$permiso2="";
}
if($row["fecha_modificacion"]==""){
$fech="";
$fechamodi="";
}else{
$fech="Ult Fecha Modificación: ";
$fechamodi=date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($row["fecha_modificacion"]));
}
echo "</tr>"; 
echo "<td width=\"90\"><center><font face=\"verdana\">";
echo "<a title='Agregado el ".date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($row["fecha_envio"]))." ".$fech." ".$fechamodi."'>".$row["dia"]."<br>".date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row["fecha_reporte"]))."<br><span style='color:#FF0000'>".$diafest1."</span>
    </font></center></a></td>";
        if($quien=="admin"){
echo "<td width=\"90\"><center><font face=\"verdana\">";    
echo "<a rel='pop-up2' href=\"procesa.php?nombrepro=".$row['conductor']."\" target=\"_parent\">".strtoupper(utf8_encode($row['conductor']))."</a><br>".$permiso2;
echo "</font></center></td>";   
}else{
echo "<td width=\"90\"><center><font face=\"verdana\">";
echo "<a rel='pop-up2' href=\"procesa.php?nombrepro=".base64_encode ($row['conductor'])."\" target=\"_parent\">".strtoupper(utf8_encode($row['conductor']))."</a>";
echo "</font></center></td>";
}
//VEHICULO------------------------------------
echo "<td width=\"70\"><center><font face=\"verdana\">".$row["placa"]."</font></center></td>";
//----- MUNICIPIO - HORAS-----------------
echo "<td>";
if($row["permiso"]=="si"){
echo "<center><font face=\"verdana\">"-"</font></center>";
}else{
if(($row["hora1"]=="")&&($row["hora2"]=="")){
    echo "<center><font face=\"verdana\">".$row["hora1"] . " ".$row["hora2"]."</font></center>";
    }else{  
    echo "<center><font face=\"verdana\">"
    .$row["hora1"] . " A ".$row["hora2"]."</font></center><center><font color=\"red\" face=\"verdana\">(".RestarHoras($row["hora1"],$row["hora2"]).")</font></center><br>       
    <a rel='pop-up2' href='http://urlg=".$row['placa']."&ini=".$row['fecha_reporte']."%20".date ('H:i' ,strtotime('-15 minute' , strtotime($row['hora1']))).":00&fin=".$row['fecha_reporte']."%20".date ('H:i' ,strtotime('+15 minute' , strtotime($row['hora2']))) . ":00' target='_blank'>RECORRIDO</a>";
    }
}
echo "</td>";   
// -------------- OPERARIOS-----------------------
$resultp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tabla2 WHERE codigo_viaje='".$row["codigo_viaje"]."'");
echo "<td width=\"100\"><left><font face=\"verdana\">"; 
    while ($rowp=mysql_fetch_array($resultp))
    {
if($quien=="admin"){    
  echo "<a rel='pop-up2' href=\"procesa.php?nombrepro=".quitar_tildes($rowp['operario'])."\" target=\"_parent\">".strtoupper(quitar_tildes($rowp['operario']))."<br>"."</a>";
}else{
    echo "<a rel='pop-up2' href=\"procesa2.php?nombrepro=".base64_encode ($rowp['operario'])."\" target=\"_parent\">".strtoupper(quitar_tildes($rowp['operario']))."</a>";
}
echo "<br>";
echo $rowp['hora1_operario']."-".$rowp['hora2_operario']."<br><font color=\"red\">(".RestarHoras($rowp['hora1_operario'],$rowp['hora2_operario']).")</font><br>".strtoupper($rowp['novedad_operario'])."<br>".strtoupper($rowp['apoyo'])." ".strtoupper($rowp['foraneo'])." ".strtoupper($rowp['he']); 
    echo "<hr>";
} 
 echo "</font></left></td>";
//------- MUNICIPIO------------
echo "<td>";
echo $row["municipio"]; 
echo "</td>";
//------CORREGIMIENTO----------
echo "<td>";
if($row["correg"]==""){
    echo "";
}else{
 echo strtoupper(utf8_encode($row["correg"]));
 echo "<br>";
 echo $row["hora1correg"]."-".$row["hora2correg"];
 echo "<br>";
 echo "<font color=\"red\">(".RestarHoras($row['hora1correg'],$row['hora2correg']).")</font>"; 
 echo "<br>";
 echo "<a rel='pop-up2' href='http://urlg=".$row['placa']."&ini=".$row['fecha_reporte']."%20".date('H:i' ,strtotime('-5 minute' , strtotime($row['hora1correg']))).":00&fin=".$row['fecha_reporte']."%20".date('H:i' ,strtotime('+5 minute' ,strtotime($row['hora2correg']))). ":00' target='_blank'><br>VER RECORR</a>";
}
echo "</td>"; 
//------------------------------------
echo "<td width=\"100\"><center><font face=\"verdana\">" . strtoupper($row["novedad_viaje"]). "</font></center></td>"; 
echo "<td width=\"100\"><center><font face=\"verdana\">" . strtoupper($row["fallo_viaje"]). "</font></center></td>";    
}   
 echo "</td>";  
 echo "</tr></tbody>";  
  mysql_free_result($result);
  mysql_free_result($resultp);
  mysql_close($link);
?>
</table>

Bueno aqui haciendo algo tengo una tabla donde tengo las placas (todas) y en otra tengo el listado almacenado de los viajes de los vehículos..
estuve revisando en otros foros y consultas y la idea es comparar lo que esta en el listado de los viajes (tabla viajes) con lo que esta en la tabla placas pero como hago la comparación y usando las fechas estara bien esta consulta.....
 <table width="900" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td height="15" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tectfima">&nbsp;</td>
            <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tectfima">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="15" colspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tectfima">
            
            <table class="grilla2" width="900" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">LISTADO DE VEHICULOS EN MANTENIMIENTO</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="3%" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><span class="texto">PLACA</span></td>
            <td width="27%" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><span class="texto">ESTADO</span></td>
          </tr>
              <?php       
    $query2 ="SELECT placa FROM placas WHERE placa NOT IN (SELECT placaviajes FROM viajes) AND fecha_reporte BETWEEN '".$fecha1w."' AND '".$fecha2w."' GROUP BY placa ORDER BY placa ASC";
 $resultw = mysql_query($query2);
    while($roww = mysql_fetch_array($resultw))
{
echo "<tbody>";
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $roww["placa"];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<b>VEHICULO NO SALIÓ, EN MANTENIMIENTO</b>";
    echo "</td>";
 echo "</tr></tbody>"; 
}
  mysql_free_result($resultw);
?>


Los comentarios han sido movidos al chat; por favor, no continuar la discusión aquí. Antes de publicar un comentario bajo este, por favor revisa los propósitos de los comentarios. Los comentarios que no pidan clarificaciones o sugieran mejoras normalmente deben ser publicados como una respuesta, en [meta], o en el [chat]. Los comentarios que continúen la discusión podrán ser eliminados.

Por lo conversado en los comentarios entiendo que:

En la tabla placas están todos los vehículos
En la tabla viajes están todos los vehículos que realizaron un viaje entre esas fechas.
La forma de relacionar un vehículo es a través de placas.placa y viajes.placaviajes.

Entonces, una solución podría ser la siguiente:

Primero necesitamos obtener la placa de los vehículos que viajaron entre las fechas ingresadas.
SELECT DISTINCT placaviajes 
FROM viajes 
WHERE fecha_reporte BETWEEN '[FECHA_A]' AND '[FECHA_B]'


Luego queda buscar la placa de los vehículo que tenemos registrados, pero que NO viajaron (que sería lo mismo que excluir lo que devuelve la consulta anterior)
SELECT placa 
FROM placa 
WHERE estado='activo' 
  AND relleno = 'no' 
  AND placa NOT IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT placaviajes 
      FROM viajes 
      WHERE fecha_reporte BETWEEN '[FECHA_A]' AND '[FECHA_B]'
  )
ORDER BY placa ASC




PD: Se puede obtener el mismo resultado realizando un LEFT JOIN pero considero que esta es la forma más fácil de verlo y entenderlo.

creo que hay que corregir algo ... el quiere que en la misma tabla (Output html) se muestren los dos estados, tanto la que viajo como la que no ... y por que no viajo ... motivo por el cual le pedia que mostrara la estructura de las tablas que tiene ... y si no tiene en una el motivo del que no viajo no lo podra tener visualmente ...

@FranciscoNuñezIALover, entiendo que puede que eso fuera lo que inicialmente queria lograr, pero en la actualización agregó el HTML de una nueva tabla con "LISTADO DE VEHICULOS EN MANTENIMIENTO"

asi esta bien hacerlo en una tabla adicional.. para no complicarnos MIL GRACIASSSSSSS Funcionó Perfecto,,,,
